# How to remove and set the view of the dialog box in the adaptor class?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog, adaptor

**Getting the error:**
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

**Issue:** Because I am calling the alert builder repeatedly so first I have to remove the view then need to set the view again.

**Problem:** I don't know how to remove and set the view in the adaptor.

```
public class ActionAdaptor extends SectionRecyclerViewAdapter<SectionHeader, Action, SectionViewHolder, ActionChildGoal> {


    Context context;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    HealthVitalsFunction interfaceAdapter;

    public ActionAdaptor(Context context, List<SectionHeader> sectionItemList) {
        super(context, sectionItemList);
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
    }


    @Override
    public SectionViewHolder onCreateSectionViewHolder(ViewGroup sectionViewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.section, sectionViewGroup, false);
        return new SectionViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public  ActionChildGoal onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup childViewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.action_list, childViewGroup, false);
        return new ActionChildGoal(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindSectionViewHolder(SectionViewHolder sectionViewHolder, int sectionPosition, SectionHeader section) {
        sectionViewHolder.name.setText(section.getSectionText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(final ActionChildGoal holder, int sectionPosition, final int childPosition, final Action action) {



        //for more options

        //When nothing is there..
        if (action.getBenefits().length()==0 && action.getSideEffects().length() == 0 && action.getRemarks().length()==0){
            holder.moreOptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.actionSubSection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {

            String msg=" ";

            if (action.getSideEffects().length()!=0)
                msg=msg.concat("<br /> <strong>Side Effects</strong> <br /> "+action.getSideEffects());

            holder.actionSubSection.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));

            holder.actionSubSection.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    showDialogBox("More Information ",holder.actionSubSection);
                }
            });

        }


    public void showDialogBox(String title, View text)
    {


        final AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context,R.style.AlertBoxTheme));
        alert.setView(new TextView(context));

        text.setPadding(3,0,3,0);
        alert.setView(text);
        alert.setTitle(title);


        alert.setPositiveButton("READ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `alert.setView` 2 times. That's the problem.

Comment: Ok If I remove both of them, then also I am getting the same error.

Comment: You need to set the view only once

Comment: I have set it to only one time. and add  TextView message=new TextView(context);
        alert.setView(message); but now I am getting the error token null is not for an application

Comment: this error is unreleated, what context are you passing in ActionAdaptor contructor?

Comment: adaptor calling activity. @Manza

Comment: I don't understand. What type of context?

Comment: I am calling the adaptor in the class so passing the that activity class context.  ActionAdaptor mAdapter=new ActionAdaptor(getApplicationContext(),sectionHeaders);
        ActionList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132114/discussion-between-manza-and-ankur-khandelwal).

Answer (score 0):

This line is problem:

```
     alert.setView(text);
```

You are trying to set view  for alert dialog with view which is currently added in RecyclerView, you need to create new one or inflate similar from xml.

Comment: so how will I overcome the problem?

Comment: Remove this line, and create leave one with setView(new TextView(context)) and set text on this textview.

Comment: I have try but now I am getting the error Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application